# Constructing holomorphic odd functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, even-and-odd-functions

Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Re(z) \geq 0$ satisfying $f(-it) = -f(it)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Can $f$ be analytically continued to an entire function $g$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $g(-z) = -g(z)$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I believe this should hold with
$$
g(z) = \begin{cases}
f(z) &\mbox{ if } \Re(z) \geq 0\\
-f(-z)&\mbox{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}
$$
It is clearly holomorphic on both $\Re(z) > 0$ and $\Re(z) < 0$. It remains to show it is holomorphic on a neighbourhood containing $i\mathbb{R}$, which should follow from the constraint above. But I'm not sure how to make this precise.

Comment: I don't understand your first assumption. If $f$ is holomorphic at a point with $\Re(z) =0$, then it is analytic and therefore has a power series convergent in a whole disk centered at that point. It is automatically analytically continued by definition.

Comment: The power series thus defined is odd, because since the analytic functions $f(z)$ and $g(z) =-f(-z) $ are equal in the subset $\Re(z) =0$ (because $f$ was required to be odd there), they must be equal along the connected component of the part of their common domain where they coincide (everywhere).

Comment: Thanks Compacto. If I understand correctly: Since $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\Re(z) \geq 0$, it must be so in an open neighbourhood of $i\mathbb{R}$. Similarly for $-f(-z)$. Then there is an open neighbourhood $N$ of $i\mathbb{R}$ where both $f(z)$ and $-f(-z)$ are holomorphic. Since $f(z) = -f(-z)$ for all $z \in i \mathbb{R} \subset N$, the identity theorem implies $f(z) = -f(-z)$ everywhere on $N$. Then from the definition of $g$ above, it follows $g(z) = f(z)$ on $N$. In particular $g$ is holomorphic on $N$.

Comment: Yes, and such a function actually must be entire, because it is defined on the whole left half-plane simply by oddness (and is holomorphic there, as you already noted).